# How to pass a parameter to a Spring Cloud Function?

Tags: spring-cloud, query-string, spring-cloud-function

I'm following the [Spring Cloud Function](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-function) tutorial.

In the example, they are calling the `revert` bean with this command:

```
curl localhost:8080/reverseString -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "abc"
```

I like to call the endpoint from a browser/postman as a GET request.

So I was looking to orchestrate a URL with a query parameter, that may look like `localhost:8080/reverseString?input=abc`

But:

1. It is not clear to me what should be the name of the parameter?
2. Seems like no matter what method name we put, they all get `HTTP 200` response, with no response body. `reverseStringggg`, `reve` ...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as `localhost:8080/reverseString/abc`

That said, I've raise the issue to explicitly support http parameters - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/864